# Move HTTP calls outside the Transaction in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, http, kotlin

We have our project in Kotlin and springboot as the framework. 
In our service class, we have bunch of code where we have few `http` calls inside a method marked with `@Transactional`.

I need to move the http calls outside the transaction as this can create performance issue.

The code looks something like this :

```
@Transactional
Method1() {
   “HTTP Call”
    Saving to DB
    “Call to another service B()”
}
```

And inside this `service B`, we are calling a `Method2()`

```
Method2() {
 Bunch of operations and then it further Saves few objects to DB.
}
```

So basically the `@Transactional` is taking care of all the nested DB operations as well.

Any suggestions how to go about this change ? What different strategies can be employed to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Does the outcome of the http calls influence the result of the transaction?

Comment: Yes. Its a call to another service which fetches some records and then we save it to the DB and then return the object from the method.

Comment: Move the saving to another method (external service) make that transactional and don't make the other transactional.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated my question as I just stumbled upon something more complex. 

So now what I am assuming (and should be happening in reality as well) is that initially when Method1() was with `@Transactional` it was taking care of all the nested DB operations as well, in service B as well.

But if I just move the `Saving to DB` out of the Method1() and marking this new method with @Transactional it will mess up my nested DB operations.

Comment: That wasn't part of your question. Everything that should be transactional should be in a single method. If that isn't possible, then just leave it as is. Also why would it be a performance problem? The time it takes for the TX is probably fractions of what it takes to make those HTTP calls.

Comment: Measure and convince them otherwise. The gain will be neglicable I suspect. Else move all the data access code to a single method which is transactional. If that isn't possible, well then it simply isn't possble.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for your input though.

Comment: @M.Deinum I just read there is something called `TransactionTemplate.doInTransaction()`. Can I use it in my scenario ?

Comment: You could, but if the `@Transactional` won't fit your needs, this won't either.

Comment: Yeah. I have done something and tried to extract all the DB calls to a single function and annotated it with @Transactional. Let's see now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to solve this issue. I had to change my approach from using the declarative transaction management to programmatic approach.

```
Method1() {
   “HTTP Call”
    TransactionTemplate.execute() {        // used this for the transaction management.
      Saving to DB
   } 
    “Call to another service B()”
}
```

And then in service B

```
Method2() {
    “Another http call”
    TransactionTemplate.executewithoutResult(){    // used TransactionTemplate.executewithoutResult because this time I did not want the transaction to return me the result. 
         Saving to DB
   } 
}
```